# Issue pulling data from API using Fetch in Native React

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "CariId": 2,
  "CariBakiyeyeSadeceOnayliFaturalarYansisin": false,
  "DonemId": 1,
  "BasTarih": "01.01.2021",
  "BitTarih": "01.01.2023"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.30:2828/CodesAndroid.svc/CariHesapListesiDetayli", requestOptions);
    const result = await response.text();
    const parsedResult=JSON.parse(result);
    const deneme =JSON.parse(parsedResult)
    setData(parsedResult);
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

```html
<View style={{flex:0.5}}>
  <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View >
            <Text style={{color:'red'}}>{data}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.CariId}/>

</View>
```

I can get the data from the API with the help of Javascript, but I don't know how to get it one by one? My research has yielded no results. I would be very happy if you could help.

Comment: How is SQL server relevant to your question?

Comment: I'm getting data from the server, but I can't call them one by one, and all the incoming data comes in the form many times.

Comment: "{\"Hareketler\":[{\"Devir\":1,\"EskiBelgeNo\":null,\"Belge\":null,\"Id\":null,\"BelgeTarihi\":\"2021-01-01T00:00:00\",\"BelgeTipi\":null,\"BelgeNo\":null,\"CariId\":2,\"BaslikKur\":null,\"BelgeAciklama\":null,\"KullaniciId\":null,\"BelgeOzelKod1\":null,\"BelgeOzelKod2\":null,\"Toplam\":0.000000,\"Bakiye\":-200.000000,\"SiraNo\":4}]}" my datas comes like that

Comment: You don't appear to be showing you backend code. Certainly nothing database like. We can't guess how you access your database.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.30:2828/CodesAndroid.svc/CariHesapListesiDetayli", requestOptions);
    const result = await response.text();
    const parsedResult=JSON.parse(result);
    const deneme =JSON.parse(parsedResult)
    setData(parsedResult);
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);  using fetch

Comment: Is there a reason that you are doing `const result = await response.text()` instead of `const result  = await response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

I think your error has nothing to do with your fetch and more to do with data initialized to null here:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

On the first render null doesn't have a map  property. So I think it is throwing an error before the fetch can even complete. So if you initialize it to

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

that should get you pass the first render. After that you can figure out if your fetch is the issue

Comment: Yeah I fixed but nothing change unfortunatelly :(